# Unit testing non-public methods in dotnet core controller

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core

Suppose in an MVC5 controller I had a method in my controller that gets called by other methods in the controller, but I don't want it available to a user. If I wanted to be able to mock it, it would look like this:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public virtual string DoSpecialFormatting(string mySpecialString)
{
    // stuff
}
```

Or I could have tossed `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyLittleProject.Tests")]` and `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]` (for Moq) into `AssemblyInfo.cs` and marked the method as `internal` instead of `public`:

```
internal virtual string DoSpecialFormatting(string mySpecialString)
{
    // stuff
}
```

Now that there is no `ChildActionOnly` and I don't see an `AssemblyInfo.cs` file in my new ASP.NET Core project, how would I have methods in my controller class which web users cannot access but can still be mocked?

Comment: One way what you can do is , have all your internal logic in a shared framework project and then use InternalsVisibleTo in for your test project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core the attribute is called `NonActionAttribute`.

```
[NonAction]
public virtual string DoSpecialFormatting(string mySpecialString)
{
    // stuff
}
```

Imho its better than internal.

Comment: Thank you, this was just what I was looking for. I was hoping to be able to do this without extracting to another class, especially for methods that make lots of use of server state.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract that method to a class , i.e. named SpecialFormatter, and inject to the controller via DI. To test your controller you can mock this class.

```
class SpecialFormatter
{ 
   public string DoSpecialFormatting(string mySpecialString)
   {
       // stuff
   }
}
```

Then in your controller

```
class SomeController : Controller
{

   private SpecialFormatter _formatter;

   public SomeController(SpecialFormatter formatter)
   {
      _formatter = formatter;
   }

   public ActionResult SomeAction(string input)
   {
      string output = _formatter.DoSpecialFormatting(input);
      // stuff
   }

}
```

Comment: If you do this you should give the extracted class an interface and pass that into the constructor of the class. This way you can inject a mock class into the class as long as it shares the common interface. As you have it right now you can only inject the concrete implementation in and will not be able to mock it out properly.